# Destroying particle systems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game there is a ball hits a coin then the coin disappeared and a particle system is initialized.

my problem is to destroy the particle system i tried to write

```
Destroy(effect.gameObject)
```

but i got an error message tell me that there is no definition for gameObject.

my unity version is 4.6.3

Help will be appreciated.

**this is my code**

```
public class CoinDestroyer : MonoBehaviour {
   public Transform coinEffect;
   void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other){
       if (other.tag == "Player"){
           var effect = Instantiate(coinEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
           Destroy(effect.gameObject, 3);
           Destroy(gameObject);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate returns an object of type Object, the top class in Unity (not the .NET type). Since you use var effect, the compiler is fine making effect an Object. But you need a GameObject since Object has no gameObject member.

```
var effect = (GameObject)Instantiate(coinEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

This is one of the danger of using var instead of strongly type variables. Best would be:

```
GameObject effect = (GameObject)Instantiate(coinEffect, transform.position, transform.rotation);
```

In this case, if the cast is missing the compiler will throw an error complaining that Object cannot be GameObject and you need a cast.

I only use var in cases I am 100% sure of the type and it is a long one to write like `KeyValuePair<string,List<GameObject>>`, else, always the right type.

Comment: there's a fun question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254388/ui-text-multiline-uneven-alignment/35258191#35258191 any ideas or know a pack that does it?  happy superbowl :)

Comment: @fafase Thanks for response.

i have edited my code.

but i got an error tell me that i can't cast from source type to destination type.

Comment: Make coin effect of GameObject type.

Comment: @fafase i have edited my code to be.  
**GameObject effect =(GameObject) Instantiate(coinEffect,transform.position, transform.rotation);**  
but i got the error of casting.  
also i edited the declaration of coinEffect to be  
**public GameObject coin effect**  
but i got the same error.

Comment: i meant this error "can't cast from source type to destination type" . . my code works well without editing anything except writing "GameObject" instead of "var" . . i edited my code before and tried to run my game but i had the error i told you about . i don't know how it works now :) . . anyway Thanks a lot man.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because the object containing effect is destroyed, I recomiedo you use a script within the system of particles insideof the  script should give a life time with the following script:

```
lifeTime = 1.0f
void Start() {
    Invoke ("SelfDestruct", lifeTime);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response , my problem is already solved . .  but you brought my attention to an important  part but i think that the particle system itself doesn't destroyed cause i store it into a new variable called effect so anytime when i want to destroy this particle i can do this.