# UI Text multiline uneven alignment

Tags: user-interface, text, unity-game-engine, textbox

The text is a string with undefined number of words. The alignment should be something like this:

```
        The text is starting from here
    then when the line is over it
goes to the next line etc.
```

Is it possible to align text this way in Unity using UI components?

Comment: As far as I know, no, you will have to make a script in which you add spaces to your text

Comment: The answer is unfortunately No.  That's very obscure!  Just for the record, you could do it with a RenderTexture, splitting it up and sliding it :)

Comment: Note that if you google for this, solutions mentioned including using a RenderTexture. That's way too hard if you're a beginning.

Comment: Just FTR another idea, theoretically, is to use multiple cameras on the UI and displace strips of the text box!  I guess that would work.

Comment: Even tho RederTexture should work it seems like overdoing the task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way built-in.

Note that Unity **DOES NOT** offer "text length" functions - **as for example iOS does**.

I really cannot think of anyway at all to find out "where it wraps" a line.  You could, perhaps, iterate over each character one by one growing the string one character at a time, and when the width stops increasing, you know, it has wrapped.  (Get the width with `.renderer.bounds.size.x` )

I would probably encourage you to just have say three `UI.Text` and separate your string.  Simply, separate the string in to say chunks of 50 characters (stopping at a space) or perhaps seven words. (They won't be exactly the same length, but it will be fine.)

**NOTE**

If you're a new Unity programmer or hobbyist, the usual solution to things like this is to

**"USE AN ASSET!"**

Someone somewhere has probably programmed what you need. So start googling for something like "free asset, wrap text around a shape" or similar.  Often, it pays to email the people who make such packages, and they often know something that does what you need, if their one does not.

Example .. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/text-box.124906/

I easily found that by googling `unity3d text utility wrap around a shape`

---

Here's some code to split a LONG line of reasonable text, in to a number of lines of length limit say 50 characters.  Note that the text must be "reasonable", you can't have any ridiculously long words etc.

```
string wholeSentence = "Your whole sentence here ... goes on and on.";

List<string> words = new List<string>(
  wholeSentence
  .Split(new string[] { " " },
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
  );

List<string> finalLines = new List<string>();

int count = 0;
string nextLine = "";
foreach (word w in words)
  {
  nextLine = nextLine + w + " ";
  count += w.Length;
  if (count>50)
   {
   finalLines.Add(nextLine);
   count=0;
   nextLine = "";
   }
  }

if (nextLine!="") finalLine.Add(nextLine);
```

that will give you all the lines, in the `List` "finalLines" !   Cheers

Comment: Everyone have a nice Superbowl50 !

Comment: I could think of something but not necessarily good way. Considering each line gets x characters, first divide the original string into sub string of x characters making sure the last word is not cut in the middle (if so placed in next line). Invert the array of string so last is first index. Iterate the array, each index is a line and the index is used to push the starting point. You can then multiply the index to push for more than just i.

Comment: Thank for the comprehensive answer! This asset is indeed exactly what I was asking for. Thought for me it will be enough to split string and place it to separate text boxes. Cheers!